# Can Selenium Web driver helps to extract data from DB

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Currently client told to extract huge data from DB, can we do that using Selenium Webdriver?

If Yes.. Please tell me the steps to do?
If No.. Please tell me is there any other way to do ?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this using selenium webdriver.

If you are using java then use JDBC to connect with your DB and then extact data according to your need.

Refer:-

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is not what you want here, it is an API used to perform test automation, not database read/writes.

You need to find out which programming language your client requires you to code in (.NET, Java, Python etc.) and then research how to connect to databases and perform read/writes.

Whichever language you use there are thousands of examples online.